# Pass Powershell array variable to workflow as parameter to workflow task?

Tags: arrays, powershell, workflow

I created this code to run Powershell scripts using workflows based on how many USB drives are mounted. If more than one is mounted, I want Powershell to run the script on every drive in parallel. The code works if I hard code the drivename parameter that foo.ps1 requires within the workflow, but I'd prefer to pass the array results to the workflow if possible. This code calls the workflow but immediately returns "Cannot Index into a Null Array", which I am assuming means the workflow doesn't know about the array. Is there a way I can pass array elements as parameters in invoking the individual workflow elements?

```
workflow Verify1 {
powershell -file Foo.ps1 $MountedDrives[0] 
}
workflow Verify2 {
 parallel
{
powershell -file Foo.ps1 $MountedDrives[0] 
powershell -file Foo.ps1 $MountedDrives[1]
}
}
$MountedDrive=@(Get-WMIObject cim_logicaldisk | ? drivetype -eq 2 | %{$_.deviceid})
$Reps = $MountedDrives.Count
switch ($Reps)
{
     1 {Verify1}
     2 {Verify2}
}
```

Comment: You hae two problems. The first is that `$Mountedrive` is missing a `D` and an `s`. The second is that `$MountedDrives` won't be visible to the workflows. You'll want to add a `param` block to your workflows and then pass the arguments explicitly

Comment: Use Foreach with -Parallel : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 1):

The answer was actually provided by mathias jessen in the first comment, I needed a param statement. What I forgot is I also needed to send the parameter when calling the workflow, otherwise the workflow wouldn't get the parameter.

```
workflow Verify1 {
param($MountedDrives)
powershell -file foo.ps1 $MountedDrives[0]
}
workflow Verify2 {
param($MountedDrives)
 parallel
{
powershell -file foo.ps1 $MountedDrives[0] 
powershell -file foo.ps1 $MountedDrives[1]
}
}
$MountedDrives=@(Get-WMIObject cim_logicaldisk | ? drivetype -eq 2 | %{$_.deviceid})
$Reps = $MountedDrives.Count
$Drive=$MountedDrives
write-host $Drive $MountedDrives
switch ($Reps)
{
     1 {Verify1 $MountedDrives}
     2 {Verify2 $MountedDrives}
}
```